# Average of two dimensional array

Tags: matlab

I have one dimensional array and i need to calculate it's average.

I tried:

`A = mean(mean(PSNRarr,2),2)`

but I get an error.

If someone knows how to make it work it will be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
mean(mean(PSNRarr))
```

*more characters to get over SO minimum*.

Comment: I tried this, but I get:

??? Undefined function or method 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.


Error in ==> mean at 28
  y = sum(x)/size(x,dim);

Error in ==> Demo at 157
              AvgPSNR= mean(mean(PSNRarr));

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way that works for any amount of dimensions (assuming it is a regular matrix):

```
 mean(PSNRarr(:))
```

However, if you have a cell array with numbers, try:

```
mean(mean(cell2mat(PSNRarr)))
```

Comment: +1: I think your solution is better; much less computational effort, more elegant. In the last case, you could even do `mean([PSNRarr{:}])` (depending of course on the specifics of `PSNRarr`).

Comment: I think this answer is better too.